# Can't Start Ignite in embedded mode with spring Configuration while constructing JavaIgniteContext

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am trying to start a JavaIgniteContext to perform basic operations on JavaIgniteRDDs. I can't find a constructor to start JavaIgniteContext with Ignite starting in embedded mode using the given Spring Cache configuration XML file. Here is my code that I am using to start Ignite context:

```
 /** Creates Ignite context with above configuration configuration */
        JavaIgniteContext igniteContext = new JavaIgniteContext(sparkContext, new IgniteOutClosure<IgniteConfiguration>() {
            @Override
            public IgniteConfiguration apply() {
                return new IgniteConfiguration();
            }
        }, false);
```

But above code uses default Spring configuration. I want to use mine. can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no such constructor in `JavaIgniteContext`. But to my knowledge, embedded mode is not working very well, so I would recommend to use standalone mode with clients on executors.